# Can I customize cloning in Script.aculo.us's ghosting?

Tags: javascript, iframe, scriptaculous

I have a Draggable in Script.aculo.us.  I'd like to use ghosting, which clones the dragged element, so you appear to be dragging a "ghost" of the element.

However, this element contains an iframe.  When I begin the drag, the clone's iframe loads, which is annoying.  I'd like a chance to remove the iframe from the clone.  How can I do that?

(Just to complicate matters: the original and the clone appear to have the same id, so I'm not sure how I'd even tell them apart without checking their styling, which seems overly hackish.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would love an answer to this question. I submitted the bug ticket to Script.aculo.us and hopefully hear something.

https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8887/tickets/291-dragging-iframe-in-mozilla-firefox